# How can encode video with images like these [overlay a video over a fixed image] with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I use ffmpeg to composite a video image with a still image to create a final image such as the one below (where the video image "plays" on the large screen and the still image creates the illusion of a theatrical audio environment)?

[image]

Comment: not a another ? hi

Comment: Sorry, don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Asked and answered : [How can encode video with images like these (overlay a video over a fixed image) with ffmpeg?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18170/how-can-encode-video-with-images-like-these-overlay-a-video-over-a-fixed-image)

But you want to add coordinates to the movie file to scale to a specific area.

For the perspective/scale:
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-perspective

For the overlay:
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-overlay-1